# Rails auto reloading constants hack

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails' constant auto-reloading is great and really convenient for development. However, I really dislike having to create a new file for very small (e.g., one-line) top-level classes, just so that Rails knows where to look for a const definition.

I skimmed over the code for `ActiveSupport::Dependencies` and came up with the following hack (to be put in an initializer):

```
module CustomLoader

  ConstMapper = {
    # what constants are defined in what files
    'lib/models.rb' => [
      :Person, 
      :Affiliation, 
      :NamedAuthority
    ]
  }.each_with_object({}) do |(k, vs), acc|
    vs.each { |v| acc[v] = Rails.root.join(k).to_s }
  end

  def const_missing(const_name)
    if path = ConstMapper[const_name]
      if ActiveSupport::Dependencies.require_or_load(path, const_name)
        return const_get(const_name)
      end
    end
    super(const_name)
  end

end

Object.extend CustomLoader
```

This seems to be working appropriately. Is there anything I am overlooking? Is this going to break something? Are there any existing workarounds that I have overlooked?

It would be nice if `AS::Dependencies` had some way to provide a hint about where a const is defined, but as far as I can tell it doesn't have that functionality.

Am I the only person that is bothered by this issue?

Comment: I don't dislike the hack, it's nice, but I would personally prefer to use an explicit require in such case (yes I'm coming from python). keep in mind that everyone looking in your project will look for these constants defined in the standard Rails autoloading paths, and come crazy :)